# Please help me understand type attribute of web.config custom settings?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am trying to define custom settings in my web.config file and I'm pretty sure I have most of it correct and it all makes sense, except the one crucial part where I don't understand what I'm supposed to use. The tutorial I used to create my SectionHandler, didn't go into an explanation of it and MSDN isn't really helping me fully understand it either.

This comes from the tutorial I used:

```
<section name="BlogSettings" type="Fully.Qualified.TypeName.BlogSettings,   
  AssemblyName" />
```

[Link to Tutorial](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/11/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx)

This is from MSDN:

```
 type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler"
```

Yes, I am very new to ASP.NET and I'm trying to learn. I would be happy with any good references that explain what's going on here.

Comment: thank you for asking this question. i dont understand most things in the webconfig

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Description

The type Attribute of the Section in web.config is the "path" to the corresponding `ConfigurationSection` class you have implemented. The ConfigurationSection class is the class that defines the section and the possible configuration content. 
The `ConfigurationSection` is the base class of all configuration sections.

This belongs to .NET in general, not only web.config.

Check out [Unraveling the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16466/Unraveling-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration)

#### More Information

- [MSDN - ConfigurationSection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx)
- [Unraveling the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16466/Unraveling-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration)

Comment: I knew I was probably over thinking it. More often than not, that's the real problem. Thank you.

Comment: So your question is answered ? Any other questions ?

Comment: Nope, thank you. I'll accept when the time limit runs out. I got it working 100% the way I needed it to.